# Java Library To Animated Movement Between Coordinates

Tags: java, animation, lib

I am working on an application that deals with moving objects from point A to point B in a 2D space. The job of the application is to animate that transition in a given number to steps (frames).

What I am currently doing is divide the distance by the number steps, hence creating a very linear and boring movement in a straight line:

```
int frames = 25;
int fromX = 10;
int toX = 20;
double step = (toX - fromX) / frames;

List<Double> values = new ArrayList<>();
int next = start;
for (int i = 0; i < frames; i++) {
  values.add(next);
  next += step;
}
```

As a first improvement - since my poor users have to look at this misery - I would like that to be an accelerated and decelerated movement starting slow, picking up speed, then getting slower again until arrival at the destination.

For that particular case, I could probably figure out the math somehow but in the end, I want to be able to provide more complex animations that would go beyond my capabilities as a mathematician ;) I have many of the capabilities of e.g. PowerPoint or iMovie in mind.

My ask is: Is there a library that would allow me to generated these sequences of coordinates? I found a few things but they where often tied to some `Graphics` object etc which I am not using. For me it's all about Lists of Doubles.